# Download CSV through HtmlUnit and read into array

Tags: java, htmlunit

I have a page that has a button to download information in the format of a CSV file. The button opens a confirm dialog to download the file. I need to store that file to a temporary location (whether that be memory or saving to an actual file and then deleting it after) and then read the data in the CSV to an array.

I've tried the code in these questions ([question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12997871/download-file-using-htmlunit), [question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049947/htmlunit-cant-retrieve-page-after-downloading-a-file?rq=1), [question 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25136439/htmlunit-download-file), and [question 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46058444/htmlunit-set-download-location)), and it's not quite what I need - mostly because they weren't downloading a CSV and using the data in it.

I'm not sure that the ConfirmDialog is being opened, but I did add a `ConfirmHandler` returning `true` to attempt to download the file. However, I don't know where the file is downloading if it is at all.

Here's what I have happening and where I get stuck:

I log in just fine. I go to a report generator. I generate a report that opens in a new window. The new window opens fine and I catch it with a `WebWindowListener`. I then search for the "save as CSV" button on the new window. I can find that, and I can click on it, but a `System.out.print` call shows that the `ConfirmHandler` isn't firing.

```
for (DomElement e : newPage.getElementsByTagName("button")) {
    int i = 0;
    webClient.setConfirmHandler(new ConfirmHandler() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        @Override
        public boolean handleConfirm(Page arg0, String arg1) {
            System.out.println("Test"); //isn't firing
            return false;
        }
    });
    if (((HtmlButton) e).getAttribute("onclick").contains("CSV")) {
        ((HtmlButton) e).click();
    }else {
        if (i++ == (newPage.getElementsByTagName("button").size() - 1)) throw new AssertionError("CSV button not found");
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but we need more details about your problem. Do you have a problem passing t^he confirm dialog?

Comment: Updated my question. Thank you, I forgot to mention the confirm dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inspiration for this answer came from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13021720/5900977).

I really wanted to get the CSV information without downloading the file, and so I, inside of the `webWindowContentChanged(arg0)` method of my `webWindowListener`, just used `arg0.getWebWindow().getEnclosingPage().getWebResponse().getContentAsString()` and then used `String.split()` a couple times to get the information I wanted.

Here's what the code looks like so it's a little clearer:

```
webClient.addWebWindowListener(new WebWindowListener() {

    @Override
    public void webWindowContentChanged(WebWindowEvent arg0) {
        if (CSVclicked) {           //boolean that is set true when I click the download button...
            String CSV = arg0.getWebWindow().getEnclosedPage().getWebResponse().getContentAsString();

            //do things...

            CSVclicked = false; //don't use the same behavior next time the method is called...
        }
    }
});
```